# How Do I Install Canon MF8000C Printer in Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I want to install the Canon MF8000C series Printer as a network printer. I have the 64-bit .deb drivers downloaded and installed from the Canon website, and the printer does show up as a network printer in the Add Printer utility, but nothing prints when a test page is sent. Is there anything I need to do in Ubuntu to get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in the latest kernels ( https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-utopic/+bug/1507863) that prevents Canon printers from working over a LAN. The symptoms are just what you describe. Try rolling back to an older kernel.